# Как по заданному количеству битов сгенерировать случайное простое число

Tags: c#, факторизация

Задача в том,что вводится количество бит (от 512 до 1024) и нужно на его основе сгенирировать случайное простое число.подскажите как это может выглядеть
число должно быть типа BigInteger

Comment: а сколько знаков у числа?

Comment: Вообще суть вопроса не ясна, почему вам не воспользоваться классом `Random`, он генерирует случайные числа, или все же есть какая-то зависимость от битов?

Comment: мне, к сожалению, не совсем понятна задача, а именно: сгенирировать **случайное простое** число

Comment: @Monomax, биты - это и есть знаки числа. Т. е. дано n от 512 до 1024 и надо сгенерировать случайное простое число p в диапазоне 2**(n-1) <= p < 2**n.

Comment: @morphey83, ну что может быть непонятно в задаче? Мне вот абсолютно понятна, в отличие от того, как её решать...

Comment: @Qwertiyа еще нужно чтобы это сгенерированое число было типа biginteger

Answer (score 0):

```
var size = 512;
var r = new Random();
var x = new BigInteger(size, r);
```

в данном примере используется библиотека BigMath. [github](https://github.com/everbytes/BigMath)
установить пакет вы сможете командой в Package Manager

```
Install-Package BigMath
```

Пример выше, как уже указал в комментариях @Qwertiy, даст вам лишь случайное число, но не факт, что оно будет простым. поэтому ответ можно считать неверным. С другой стороны статический метод той же библиотеки *BigInteger.ProbablePrime*, судя по всему, делает именно то, что вы хотите.

Comment: Эм.. С чего сгенерированное число должно оказаться простым?

Comment: К тому же, у него нет такого конструктора: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: пространство имен BigMath.BigInteger

Comment: @Qwertiy, вы правы, ответ в не отвечает условиям ))

Comment: [Пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BigMath/) нашёл, [конструктор](https://github.com/everbytes/BigMath/blob/master/src/BigMath.PCL/BigInteger.cs#L441) - тоже, но вот сгенерированное число простым всё равно не будет.

Comment: там же есть любопытный static метод ProbablePrime

Comment: А сколько примерно чисел придётся сгенерировать, чтобы попалось простое?

Comment: такого конструктора нет у biginteger.и я не понимаю как подключить bigmath этот .можете пожалуйста изменить код чтобы было корректно.спасибо

Comment: @morphey83 такого конструктора нет у biginteger.и я не понимаю как подключить bigmath этот .можете пожалуйста изменить код чтобы было корректно.спасибо

Comment: @df9df32 я подправил ответ, но не думаю, что он стал от этого правильнее ))