# По заданному количеству бит сгенерировать простое число типа BigInteger.Язык C#

Tags: c#, biginteger, факторизация

На вход подаётся количество бит.Исходя из их количества генерируется случайное простое число типа BigInteger. Функция проверки на простоту у меня есть.но как сгенерировать из битов незнаю

Comment: Каждый бит - случайное число ноль или один.

Comment: Какая зависимость СЛУЧАЙНОГО числа и поданных на вход бит? Думаю, что как только ответите на этот вопрос - тогда и поймёте, как решать задачу. Сейчас задача вида "закодить то, не знаю что".

Comment: А не [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919073/220553) ли?

Comment: Именно `простое` число? Смотрите алгоритм создания ключа RSA.

Comment: Посчитать все простые числа, помещающиеся в эти биты, и случайно выбрать одно.

Comment: Работать будет минут 10 :) подбор длинных простых чисел. Где то видел базу сгенерированных __всех__ простых чисел, в данном случае имеет смысл делать выборку по базе, будет быстрее.

Comment: так вот мне именно для RSA и нужно.пока план у меня такой:ввожу количество битов .потом перевожу их в двоичную систему.а вот как потом сгенерировать с их помощью тип BigInteger незнаю да и число это случайным не будет

Comment: Брать все же оптимально из базы, выборка по количеству бит, потом рандом-рандже на выборку. Но лучше посмотрите готовые реализации. В любом случае, при генерации это будет очень долго, с такими условиями.